# Using Git with GitHub: `remote: Permission to username\project.git denied to myname.`

Tags: linux, git, github, git-fork

I forked an existing project I'm trying to contribute to,

I'm trying to do it the simplest way possible. From a raspberry pi.
I changed email address and project names for simplicity

I don't understand why this doesn't work, the new repository is at `https://github.com/username/project`

Please help me understand what is missing, the instructions found online for github are not sufficient

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ git config --global user.name "username"

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ git config --global user.email "username@email.com"

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ git clone https://github.com/username/project
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 23, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 1450 (delta 9), reused 16 (delta 5), pack-reused 1427
Receiving objects: 100% (1450/1450), 2.28 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1019/1019), done.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd project

pi@raspberrypi:~/project $ git add --all

pi@raspberrypi:~/project $ git commit -am "mychange"
[master 1732397] mychange
 20 files changed, 2613 insertions(+), 2248 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 newfile.cpp

pi@raspberrypi:~/project $ git push
Username for 'https://github.com': username@email.com
Password for 'https://username@email.com@github.com':
remote: Permission to username/project.git denied to myname.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/project/': The request                                                        ed URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: Could be as simple as the project doesn't allow all commits. Maybe doesn't allow commits to master. I restrict commits to master in my repos.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes there is a protection on develop and master, and you have to go through a pull request to merge.

Comment: Additionally, make sure your SSH key is configured.

Answer (score 1):

The username requested by GitHub should not be an email address.  (`username@email.com`)
It should be your GitHub user account name.

Unless you have [2FA activated](https://help.github.com/en/articles/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication), in which case, the username remains your GitHub account, but [your password would be a PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication#using-two-factor-authentication-with-the-command-line)